¿Cómo obtener intentos aleatorios en un intervalo de tiempo?
He escrito un código para estimar el uso de potencia de ciertos electrodomésticos de cocina, durante los distintos tiempos de comidas (desayuno, comida y cena) para una población de 5 millones (1 millón de viviendas). El objetivo es representar la demanda de potencia a lo largo de las 24 horas del día.
Este es el código que he hecho:
function [monthlyEnergyMWhcook,powerConsumptionMWcook] = Cooking()
% Constants for appliances (Watts)
ovenPower = 3000; % Watts (household appliance)
grillPower = 6000; % Watts (household appliance)
kettlePower = 2200; % Watts (household appliance)
toasterPower = 850; % Watts (household appliance)
microwavePower = 800; % Watts (household appliance)

% Daily usage durations in minutes, converted to number of intervals
ovenDuration = ceil((132 / 60) * (241 / 24)); % 2 hours and 12 minutes
grillDuration = ceil((126 / 60) * (241 / 24)); % 2 hours and 6 minutes
kettleDuration = ceil((11 / 60) * (241 / 24)); % 11 minutes
toasterDuration = ceil((9 / 60) * (241 / 24)); % 9 minutes
microwaveDuration = ceil((11 / 60) * (241 / 24)); % 11 minutes

% Time vector for 24-hour period (241 time steps)
timeVec = linspace(0, 24, 241);

% Initialize power consumption array
powerConsumption = zeros(1, length(timeVec));

% Define key meal preparation start times
breakfastStart = find(timeVec >= 7, 1); % 7 AM
lunchStart = find(timeVec >= 12, 1); % 12 PM
dinnerStart = find(timeVec >= 18, 1); % 6 PM

% Number of households
households = 1000000;  % Example number of households

% Appliance usage during typical meal times
% Breakfast usage
powerConsumption(breakfastStart:breakfastStart+kettleDuration-1) = (kettlePower+toasterPower+microwavePower) * households;
% Lunch usage
powerConsumption(lunchStart:lunchStart+ovenDuration-1) = ovenPower * households;

% Dinner usage
powerConsumption(dinnerStart:dinnerStart+grillDuration-1) = grillPower * households;

% Convert power consumption to MW
powerConsumptionMWcook = powerConsumption / 1000000; % Convert Watts to kW and then to MW

% Calculate total daily energy in MWh
totalEnergyMWh = sum(powerConsumptionMWcook) * (6 / 60); % Convert MW to MWh, accounting for 6 minutes per interval

% Print the total daily energy consumption
fprintf('Total daily energy consumed by cooking: %.2f MWh\n', totalEnergyMWh);
%Plotting the 24-hour power consumption for cooking
figure;
plot(timeVec, powerConsumptionMWcook);
xlabel('Time (Hours)');
ylabel('Power Consumption (MW)');
title('24-Hour Cooking Power Consumption in MW');
grid on;
%Constants
daysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];  % Days in each month

% Daily energy consumption in MWh (from previous calculation)
dailyEnergyMWh = sum(powerConsumptionMWcook) * (6 / 60); % Recalculated to ensure accuracy

% Initialize monthly energy consumption array
monthlyEnergyMWhcook = zeros(1, 12);

% Calculate monthly energy consumption
for i = 1:12
    monthlyEnergyMWhcook(i) = dailyEnergyMWh * daysInMonth(i);
end

Problema:
Mi problema es que en mi código inicio el uso del electrodoméstico en un mismo instante de tiempo, por ejemplo el millón de teteras que se activarán durante 12 minutos empiezan a la vez, por lo que genera un gran pico en el consumo de potencia y de esta forma no se representa de una forma realista.
Me preguntaba si existe alguna forma de hacer que de ese millón de viviendas solo un número aleatorio entre medio millón y 1 millón, enciendan la tetera y sobre todo si se puede hacer que en lugar de programarlo para simular que se encienden en todas las viviendas al mismo tiempo, se encendieran también en una hora aleatoria dentro de un intervalo de tiempo; es decir que entre las 8 y las 10 de la mañana solo 500 mil viviendas enciendan la tetera y que algunos lo hagan a las 8 y 5 otros a las 9 y 10, etc.
Si se necesita que aporte algo más de información, lo aportaré sin problema.
Agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda, comentario o corrección,
Muchas gracias de antemano.
